# beginner Cuda program

Tags: c, cuda

This is with ref to the code http://wind.d.umn.edu/acmclub/sites/default/files/summation.cu provided at http://wind.d.umn.edu/acmclub/?q=node/12
Im a beginner programmer but still I could follow the code and explanation except for few things.

1.] What is the meaning of "new" in this line taken from summation.cu

sum_h = new unsigned long();

2.]Also I really couldnt understand this code. What purpuse does strtoul serve ? I'd be thankful if you could point to some beginners resource on "new" & "strtoul"

```
n = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0);
```

3.] Is the code "summation.cu" written completely in C++. So inorder to code CUDA programs do I need to learn C++ instead of C? Or do I need to learn both C & C++ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it short:

1. `new` allocates memory (e.g. for the sum) (see [details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_%28C++%29))
2. `strtoul` converts a string to a long (see [details](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/))
3. I think you should start with [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) (e.g. C++ Primer) and learn some C later (e.g. from [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672326663)). After that I would start with
   CUDA.

Keep your chin up.

Comment: Thanks!!! BTW I already have finished python, so can I code for CUDA in python rather than going for C/C++. If not ,then as suggested by you I'll start with C++ rather than C .

Comment: @vinita CUDA in python - never thought about that - sounds cool, I'll have a look at it - thx

Comment: Yeah there's something called PYCUDA.

Answer (score 1):

1. As Saviour Self pointed out in the comments - new means dynamic memory allocation on the heap at runtime. More information [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_dynamic_memory.htm).
2. I think this is pretty much similar to the C-function `atoi` that converts a number stored as a char into a integer. In you case this should convert the number (stored as char) in `argv[1]` into a `unsigned long int`. Check it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoul/).
3. The language used in CUDA is called "C for CUDA" and as long as I've been reading and learning you can code in C but there are many features of C++ that are also supported. You can start taking a look at [CUDA DOCUMENTATION](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/index.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: `new` meaning dynamic memory allocation on the heap at runtime. More information here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_dynamic_memory.htm

Comment: @SaviourSelf that's more than correct. I'll edit the post. Thanks for the reference.